# Desktop client for webapp with notifications

Tags: web-applications, air, client, desktop-application

I'm looking for best approach - maybe some pre-made framework to make a **desktop-client for web app** /chat/

What I need is option to make an app displaying a web content with added functionality to **display system notifications** somehow /info-bubble from tray? alert window? flashing icon in tray?, ../ to notify there is something new requiring the response from user
option to make it start on system start would be great.

So far the best approach I know about is **Adobe Air** - I know it can wrap a custom web app with predefined window size and html/url to load, and to make a "desktop icon" but I don't know if there is anything better? This requires the air to be available for the *.air installer, I'm looking for option to generate something stand-alone without next special pre-requisites.

Most important target is Windows XP/7, a possibility to export for OS X too would be a great advantage.

Comment: just found following nice comparison, please share your opinions and suggestions http://blog.neamlabs.com/post/36584972328/2012-11-26-web-app-cross-platform-desktop-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Air fits your requirements:

- System tray: (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/SystemTrayIcon.html)
- Info-bubble from tray: (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html)
- Standalone: (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html)
- Windows XP/7, possibility to export for OsX: (http://www.adobe.com/de/products/air/tech-specs.html)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5's notification API allows you to display notification on almost any platform through Firefox, Chrome or Safari (http://caniuse.com/notifications).

(e.g of [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications) of HTML5's notification)

So if you're ok with lunching your app inside a browser then just open it with your browser.

If you want a more native feel (no Browser's UI, Shortcut on desktop, Install/Uninstall, etc...) then I see three solutions :

- Open Web apps from Mozilla
- Web apps from Google (Chrome's Store)
- Export to packaged Native app through PhoneGap, Cordova, Node-Webkit, etc...

Using HTML5's API is a much better bet than Adobe Air concerning long term support. However you'd have to check how well HTML5's notification API is supported in the solutions I gave.
Also notice that Open Web Apps and Google's web app need respectively Firefox or Chrome to be installed. If you want everything packaged as an executable, you'd better try the 3rd solution.